# Taylor series only holds for specific interval?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am reading from a book which states, and I quote:

> [...] since $(1+z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n$ when $0<z<1$ [...]

What precedes is irrelevant. I am happy with the first part (i.e that $(1+z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n$). This is a result of a Taylor Series expansion of the function about $z=0$. What I am not happy with is the second part. Why must this only hold true for interval $0<z<1$? It was my understanding that the Taylor Series could hold true for an ever increasing interval depending on how many sums are included in it. The book clearly states that this is a summation to infinity. That is, at infinity this will hold true for all $z$. Please let me know what I am missing here...

Comment: The statement "the Taylor Series could hold true for an ever increasing interval depending on how many sums are included in it" is simply not true.

Comment: Is it not? The more terms we include, the closer it gets to the original function we are trying to approximate. This is shown by the animation on this wikipedia link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Exp_series.gif)

Comment: Yes, the better the approximation gets, within the interval of convergence.  With the infinite number of terms we get equality, but still within that same interval of convergence.

Comment: Just try it!  See what happens to the given series for, say, $z=1$, $z=2$, $z=-2$.  You'll see that it certainly doesn't converge to $(1+z)^{-1}$; in fact it doesn't converge at all.

Comment: You only get convergence on the entire real line if your function is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).  The exponential function is entire, which is why you would see that behavior in the animation you linked.  But it's not the general case.  Another interesting example is $(1+z^2)^{-1}$ which is smooth everywhere on the real line, yet its Taylor series around $z=0$ only converges on $(-1,1)$.  (This is basically because there are singularities at $\pm i$.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am happy with the first part (i.e that $(1+z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n$).

I think this is a good place to start, since understanding when the "$=$" is true is the whole point (and I would say that you haven't completely understood this until you understand that it *must* come with a condition on $z$).

Recall the finite result
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n z^n = \frac{1-(-z)^{N+1}}{1+z}, $$
which is true for any $z \neq -1$ (where the denominator on the right vanishes). The definition of an infinite sum is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n; $$
the sum *converges* if and only if the limit on the right exists. In order for this to exist, therefore, the limit of the finite sums must exist. But for your example, the limit only exists when $\lvert z \rvert < 1$: if $\lvert z \rvert \geq 1 $, the term $-(-z)^{N+1}/(1+z)$ does not tend to zero (indeed, if $\lvert z \rvert >1$, $\lvert(-z)^{N+1}\rvert$ grows larger and larger). Meanwhile, if $\lvert z \rvert < 1$, $\lvert z \rvert^{n+1}<\lvert z\rvert^{n}$, so
$$ \left| \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n z^n - \frac{1}{1+z} \right| = \left| \frac{(-z)^{N+1}}{1+z} \right| \to 0 $$
as $N \to \infty$. Thus what is actually true is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^n = \frac{1}{1+z} \qquad (\lvert z \rvert < 1),$$
while for $\lvert z \rvert \geq 1$, the series does not converge.

---

Now, let's talk about Taylor series more generally. Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ be the Taylor series of some function (about $z=0$, naturally). When does this series converge? Or, more pertinently, when does it not converge? Suppose there's a point $w$ where the series does not converge (in your example, $z=-1$ is an easy place to check: then the series is $1+1+1+\dotsb$, which obviously doesn't converge). Then
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N a_n z^n = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n w^n \left( \frac{z}{w} \right)^n $$
But $\lvert a_n w^n \left( \frac{z}{w} \right)^n \rvert < \lvert a_n w^n \rvert \lvert \frac{z}{w} \rvert^n $. For the series to converge, these terms must tend to zero. But $\lvert \frac{z}{w} \rvert^n \to \infty$ since $\lvert \frac{z}{w} \rvert>1$, so for the terms to tend to zero, we must have $\lvert a_n w^n \rvert  \leq K\lvert \frac{w}{z} \rvert^n $ for some $K>0$. But then
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \lvert a_n w^n \rvert \leq K\sum_{n=0}^{N} \lvert w/z \rvert^n, $$
and we saw above that the series on the right converges, which means that the power series evaluated at $w$ actually converges absolutely, contradicting our assumption that it diverges.

Hence if the series diverges at any point, it diverges for all points further away from the expansion point. Since your series diverges for $z=-1$, it must diverge for all $\lvert z \rvert >1$.

---

Underlying all this is the other question: suppose a Taylor series converges. To what does it converge? Thankfully, the function for which it is the Taylor series! The proof of this can be made a bit silly by writing down a certain integral, that comes from iterated integration by parts:
$$ \frac{1}{k!}\int_a^x (x-t)^k f^{(k+1)}(x) \, dx = f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n. $$
So, if this integral tends to zero as $k \to \infty$, the Taylor series converges to the function. Most of the time this is quite easy to check.